# Use different site maps in an EXT TreePanel

Tags: asp.net, ext.net, sitemapprovider

This is the ASP.NET snippet:

```
<ext:TreePanel ID="tpPanel" runat="server" UseArrows="true" Width="220">
```

And this is the C# code behind it:

```
tpPanel.Root.Add(this.CreateNode(SiteMap.RootNode, user.IsAdmin, user.UserPrivilege));
```

The `CreateNode` is our internal method. What I'd like to do is to load different sitemaps depending on user setting, like this:

```
if(userID == 1)
    tpPanel.Root.Add(this.CreateNode(<<sitemap1object>>, user.IsAdmin, user.UserPrivilege));
else
    tpPanel.Root.Add(this.CreateNode(<<sitemap2object>>, user.IsAdmin, user.UserPrivilege));
```

I have the sitemaps in XML in `Web.sitemap_1` and `Web.sitemap_2` files. The first argument to `CreateNode` is a `SiteMapNode` object that points to the site map, but what I have here only points to the default map. I want to do this using the `SiteMapNode Constructor (SiteMapProvider, String)` constructor, but I have no idea how to get a `SiteMapProvider` from a string that's the location of the XML file.

Comment: Maybe the following example can help, see http://examples.ext.net/#/TreePanel/Basic/SiteMap/